# When adding a solution to a subversion repository with Tortoise, how to avoid adding unnecessary files

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using Visual Studio, but I guess this will be relevant for other platforms.

Currently, when I need to add an existing Solution or Project to Subversion with Tortoise, I add all files/folders initially, and then have to go through and weed out the ones that I don't want to be source controlled (e.g. output dlls, user settings like the suo file), and register them on the ignore lists for the relevant folders. It takes ages.

There must be a better way that I don't know about, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add specific filenames and extensions to the Global ignore pattern in the TortoiseSVN settings dialog.

[image]

My entry is as follows:

```
*.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store httpd.parse.errors *.db *.config aspnet_client *.pyc *.suo obj bin *.user Thumbs.db
```

Which seems to weed out most of the Visual Studio stuff I don't want checked in when adding a project to SVN.

Edit: [Git Ignore Examples](https://github.com/github/gitignore) — I know these are Git ignore files, but they're quite useful to see which files/folders to ignore for each language.

Comment: Thats a good list of filters. Reminds me that that blinking Thumbs.db always crops up when you're not expecting it.

Comment: Why have you got *.config in there? Do you do something special with config files?

Comment: We have a slightly odd system, where each dev creates their own web.config locally to connect to the development SQL server, set up test email addresses etc. We then check in the production config file as `web.config.live`, meaning when we deploy to the live server it doesn't overwrite the existing config (unless we specifically delete it and rename the `.live` file).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include only the relevant files, then you should consider using [AnkhSvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/), a VS2010 add-in for Subversion support. It lets you check in only the files that are included in your projects.